# How does one determine the number of eigenstates of a system with a given spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I have had a true/false question in a practice exam stating:

> For a spin 3/2 system (S=3/2), there are only four spin eigenstates.

which is true. (solutions)

I do not understand how one can determine how many eigenstates exist for a given spin system.

All I know is a s=1/2 system has two eigenstates.

Comment: A general formula for a number of the spin eigenstates is $2S+1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The states may take any value between $S$ and $-S$ in steps of 1. I.e. for $S = \tfrac{3}{2}$ valid states would be $\lbrace\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{3}{2}\rbrace$, for $S = \tfrac{1}{2}$ we get $\lbrace\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2}\rbrace$ and for $S = 2$ we get the five states $\lbrace2,1,0,-1,-2\rbrace$.

Notice that then nececarrily follows that $S$ may take only full or half integer-values.